# How to Update UISlider Value when Scroll UITableView in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uislider

When i set the Slider Value see this screenshort[image]

And then `tableview` Scrolling down then the value is changed see this screen short [image]

issue is that the value is change when i'm scrolling down i have seen lot's of answers but in Objective-C Please Help me for this in Swift. i am use Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4 Big Thank You !!

Here i will used CoreData but i just want Slider issue !!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var arrData = [String]()
    var studentData = [Student]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        studentData = DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.getAllData()
        arrData = [
            "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music1/v4/53/58/26/5358265a-e225-2cfb-61da-e6cb68ea5866/source/100x100bb.jpg","https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/3b/cf/4c/3bcf4c0d-a040-3d74-81e9-6ca62c3664ab/source/100x100bb.jpg",
            "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/4f/a6/a3/4fa6a31a-26f0-c025-4f1c-a20da9dd4a32/source/100x100bb.jpg","https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music5/v4/eb/43/a3/eb43a360-d92e-7dbd-feb8-73b8496ba66f/source/100x100bb.jpg"
        ]
        for arr in arrData{
            DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.save(object: arr)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return studentData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.studentData = studentData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
```

// TableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!
    var studentData:Student!{
        didSet{
            let url = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: studentData.photo!)!, cacheKey: studentData.photo)
            img.kf.setImage(with: url)
            slider.value = studentData.valueslider
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.saveValue(object: slider.value)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    @IBAction func sliderBtnClick(_ sender: UISlider) {
        img.alpha = CGFloat(slider.value)
    }


}
```

//Database Helper

```
class DatabaseHelper{
    static let shareInstance = DatabaseHelper()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    func save(object:String){
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student", into: context) as! Student
        entity.photo = object
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Data not save")
        }
    }

    func saveValue(object:Float){
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student", into: context) as! Student
        entity.valueslider = object
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Data not save")
        }
    }

    func getAllData() -> [Student]{
        var arrData = [Student]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Student")
        do{
            arrData = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Student]
        }catch{
            print("Data not get")
        }
        return arrData
    }
}
```

Data CoreData Class

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Student)
public class Student: NSManagedObject {

}

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Student {

 @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Student> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Student>(entityName: "Student")
 }

 @NSManaged public var photo: String?
 @NSManaged public var valueslider: Float

}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: show your `tableview` code

Comment: Please Help For Slider You can use coredata or with out core data i just want logic for that how i can achieve that ! Thank You

Comment: show me your student class

Comment: i update code pls check @Warewolf

Comment: @YogeshPatel check I have posted working code.

Comment: @Warewolf Great it's Working Thank You so so much !! Respect :)

Comment: @YogeshPatel if its working fine, then accept my answer by clicking on tick mark under my answer.

Comment: Yes @Warewolf i don't know that sorry for that !! Great Answer it's solve my query ! Thank You :)

Comment: @YogeshPatel still you haven't accepted my answer, you accepted someone else. Anyway at least upvote my answer as checked once can't be undone after a period of time.

Comment: stackoverflow give me error 15 reputation recorded upvote like i try to upvote but it not working @Warewolf

Comment: Votes cast win by less 15 reputation ??

Comment: forget it, remember it next time, if someone provide you help appreciate it with vote up even if you are unable to accept.

Comment: yes @Warewolf next time i'm take care of this thing Thank You !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protocol SliderDelegate: class {
    func sliderValueChanged(withValue: Int, cell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: SliderDelegate?
    @IBAction func sliderBtnClick(_ sender: UISlider) {
       img.alpha = CGFloat(slider.value)
       delegate?.sliderValueChanged(withValue: slider.value, cell: self)  
    }

}
```

In your View Controller's, table view datasource method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.studentData = studentData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
 }
```

And conform to Sliderdelegate

```
extension ViewController: SliderDelegate {
    func sliderValueChanged(withValue: Int, cell: TableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = yourTable.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        // Save Slider value to database (Database.save... your logic to update the slider value for the data at this indexPath, goes here) and then reload data like follows
        yourTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: there is no detailsChanged Func in Protocol SliderDelegate it is sliderValueChanged ?? And pls tell me what is orderList in my case Thank You !

Comment: i'm not able to slide my slider ? i don't know why that not slide pls help !Thank You

Comment: @YogeshPatel did you remove         `DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.saveValue(object: slider.value)`
from awakeFromNib method, and added below the comment // save slider?

Comment: Yes i remove this code form that ! And i add this code on sliderValueChange Func ? it's fine

Comment: Yes, so once your database will be updated with slider's value, and after that you reload table, you will be able to achieve what u want.

Comment: I hope you are updating the value in database? otherwise every time  you reload, slider will be reset to older value @YogeshPatel

Comment: i just want that the value not change when i scroll. the value of slider is stored but it's store 0 because the slider is not moved ? i think i'm doing wrong code can you check by above code is it right if not then pls tell me that i changed the code!! Thank You

Comment: Yes i am not update the value here i'm doing a save and get value can you provide me update code for slider value

Comment: @YogeshPatel the "value changes when you scroll" issue will be resolved with above code, but for that you need to be properly updating your database. That will be another question altogether, "how to update value in your database"

Comment: Ohk Thank you @Mansi for helping me i will update coredata value Using Protocol and delegate it really very easy to for changing value !! Great :)

Comment: Yes Sure !! @Mansi

Answer (score 0):

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, TableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var studentData = [Student]()
    var arrData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        arrData = [
            "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music1/v4/53/58/26/5358265a-e225-2cfb-61da-e6cb68ea5866/source/100x100bb.jpg",
            "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music118/v4/3b/cf/4c/3bcf4c0d-a040-3d74-81e9-6ca62c3664ab/source/100x100bb.jpg",
            "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/4f/a6/a3/4fa6a31a-26f0-c025-4f1c-a20da9dd4a32/source/100x100bb.jpg",
            "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music5/v4/eb/43/a3/eb43a360-d92e-7dbd-feb8-73b8496ba66f/source/100x100bb.jpg"
        ]

        for urlStr in arrData {
            let student = Student(fromPhotoUrl:urlStr);
            studentData.append(student);
        }

        tableView.register(TableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier())
        tableView.reloadData();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return studentData.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier(), for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let student = studentData[indexPath.row];
        cell = TableViewCell.configureCell(cell: cell, forStudent: student, atIndex: indexPath.row);
        cell.delegate = self;
        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return TableViewCell.height();
    }

    func sliderValueChanged(cell:TableViewCell, sliderChanged changedValue:Float) {
        let student = studentData[cell.tag];
        student.valueslider = changedValue;
        studentData[cell.tag] = student;
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class Student {
    var photo: String
    var valueslider:Float = 0.0;
    init(fromPhotoUrl url: String) {
        self.photo = url
    }
}

protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func sliderValueChanged(cell:TableViewCell, sliderChanged changedValue:Float);
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate:TableViewCellDelegate? = nil;
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func sliderBtnClick(_ sender: UISlider) {
        img.alpha = CGFloat(sender.value);
        self.delegate?.sliderValueChanged(cell: self, sliderChanged: sender.value);
    }

    class func nib() -> UINib {
       return UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil);
    }

    class func identifier() -> String {
        return "TableViewCell";
    }

    class func height() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.init(80);
    }

    class func configureCell(cell:TableViewCell, forStudent student:Student, atIndex index:Int) -> TableViewCell {
        //background task to get data from url
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let imgUrl = URL(string: student.photo) {
                do {
                    let imageData:Data = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl as URL)
                    // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.img.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        cell.tag = index;
        cell.slider.value = student.valueslider;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

[WORKING-CODE.ZIP](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxihxzw43j1jdkg/ScrollSlider.zip?dl=0)